# Column fields that are part of a join convert to null or 0 when exported

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I've seen similar questions on here, but none seem to resolve my specific problem. I am very new to ArcGIS Pro.

I have a shapefile of parcels that I want to join two tables to.
I use  columns with matching fields between the shapefile and each of the tables in each to create the join (so two separate joins), and the new layer's attribute table shows all the columns and data from the parcels and tables.

However, if I try to calculate fields on the new combined table, I get an error stating that one or more of the selected columns do not exist.

If I export the combined layer to  a new shapefile/feature to make the join permanent, all the columns will be there, but the data from the tables will be empty, 0, or null; the date from the shapefile is present though.

Now, I discovered that if I join the two tables to the exported feature's table and export that, all the data is there and I can perform calculations. However, I have twice the number of columns, which is annoying.

What am I doing wrong the first time around?

What is changing between the first and second exports that makes the join work?

The two tables are .dbf, and I believe the shape file was created with ArcMap (the course is taught in Map, but I feel that it is more valuable to learn Pro).

**now the re-joining/re-exporting work-around is not working either

Comment: Please include links to the similar questions that you've seen here.  That will save potential answerers having to look for them before deciding whether to answer your question.

Comment: You may try to import your shapefile and two table in a geodatabase first and do the join and calculation with your new imported data

Comment: This is a known bug. Can you upgrade to 2.7 or later Pro?

Comment: @danak I am currently using version 2.9.1

Comment: @J.R I did try that, but with the same results. everything from the joined tables is converted to 0, null, or just empty

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue from time to time.
Try the "Join Features" tool. This outputs the result of a join to a new feature class, rather than creating an in-memory join.
It is also parallel processed so it runs faster than the Add join tool/GUI as an added bonus.